# Can we please reopen this question about Cyclops' optic blasts?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

I asked a question recently: [Why was the tree burnt?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/131800/44184)

*Part* of this question is checking whether Cyclops' optic blasts produce heat. That's only part of the question because if they do, then that makes for a pretty trivial answer: the tree is burnt because the blast is hot.

The actual question, though, is "If not, why was the tree burning?".

Yet, this question has been closed as a duplicate of a question that has nothing to do with this specific instance of Cyclops hitting something with his blasts and having it light up. The only part of the answer to the "duplicate" that is even relevant is "Nor does it emit infrared radiation or heat of any kind". All that does is *justify* my question, not answer it.

Note: I'm perfectly happy to edit the question if someone has a specific suggestion.

Comment: Because even if we reopen it, the answer it makes for a trivial answer: The writers and movie producers didn't care enough to get the answer correct, instead going for cheap laughs rather than being aware of the what should have clearly been a non-burning tree.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze I strongly disagree with that. What if I find additional examples of things lighting up when Cyclops hits them in other media? Then I would be asking not about the tree specifically, but instead "why do Cyclops' optic blasts melt and burn things if they don't produce heat?" I feel like there's probably a physics based answer related to pressure producing heat.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze Also, even if what you wrote is the answer, then that's a perfectly good answer.

Comment: The question has been reopened.

Answer (score 1):

### [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Your question has been reopened by Thaddeus Howze ♦ (the same person who originally closed it) and four other users. Nobody has voted to re-close it.